# Program hangs if GCC optimizations are enabled

Tags: gcc, optimization

I'm doing some kind of "homework" on a platform (training.olinfo.it) where, given a certain problem, you have to create a program that solves it, and it must respect memory and time constraints.

The one I'm trying to solve ([bigsomma](https://training.olinfo.it/#/task/bigsomma/statement)) is the following:
*given a sequence V<sub>0</sub>, V<sub>1</sub>, ... V<sub>N-1</sub> made of N integers, find the sum of them.*
Time limit: 1 second
Memory limit: 256MiB

Assumptions:
N ≤ 50.000.000
−67 108 864 ≤ V<sub>i</sub> ≤ 67 108 863 for every 0 ≤ i ≤ N-1

I have already solved this problem, with an execution time of around 0.9s. The fact is, I was trying to optimize it even more. The platform where I'm submitting the problem does not support asynchronous reading nor threads nor pthreads, but it looks like fork() calls work. So, I set up a shared memory space with 2 buffers and some pointers. The child process reads, while the parent process calculates the sum.
The fact is, when compiling, both locally and on the platform, if some optimizations (such as -O2) are enabled, the code hangs, while when they are turned off the code works as intended. Also, the platform automatically optimizes using the "-O2" flag, so deactivating it there is not an option.

The code I wrote:

```c
#define _SVID_SOURCE

#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<assert.h>

#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast,no-stack-protector,unroll-loops,fast-math")
#pragma GCC target("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4.1,sse4.2,avx,avx2,popcnt,tune=native")

#define buf_size 0x10000

void swap(void** a, void** b){
    void* c=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=c;
}

long long somma(FILE *__restrict__ f){
    size_t size_read;
    long long sum=0;
    int current=0, neg=0, temp=0;

    //int fd=f->_fileno;
    int fd=fileno(f);
    char c;

    key_t shm_key=ftok("bigsomma_async.c", 65);
    bool *can_proceed;
    bool *acknowledge_read;
    size_t *size_read_ptr;
    char* buf_1;
    char* buf_2;
    char** buf_1_ptr;
    char** buf_2_ptr;

    int shmid=shmget(shm_key, 
                                sizeof(bool)+
                                sizeof(bool)+
                                sizeof(size_t)+
                                sizeof(char)*buf_size+
                                sizeof(char)*buf_size+
                                sizeof(char*)+
                                sizeof(char*)
                            , IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }

    char* shared_mem=(char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    can_proceed=(bool*)shared_mem;
    acknowledge_read=(bool*)(can_proceed+1);
    size_read_ptr=(size_t*)(acknowledge_read+1);
    buf_1=(char*)(size_read_ptr+1);
    buf_2=(char*)(buf_1+buf_size);
    buf_1_ptr=(char**)(buf_2+buf_size);
    buf_2_ptr=(char**)(buf_1_ptr+1);

    *can_proceed=true;
    *acknowledge_read=true;
    *size_read_ptr=1;
    *buf_1_ptr=buf_1;
    *buf_2_ptr=buf_2;

    pid_t pfork=fork();
    if(!pfork){
        while(*size_read_ptr!=0){
            while(!*acknowledge_read){}
            *size_read_ptr=read(fd, buf_2, buf_size);
            
            while(!*can_proceed){}

            /*char* tmp=*buf_1_ptr;
            *buf_1_ptr=*buf_2_ptr;
            *buf_2_ptr=tmp;*/

            swap((void**)buf_1_ptr, (void**)buf_2_ptr);

            *can_proceed=false;
            *acknowledge_read=false;
        }
        exit(0);
    }else{
        int size_read;
        while(*size_read_ptr!=0){
            while(*can_proceed){}

            size_read=*size_read_ptr;
            *acknowledge_read=true;

            for(current=0; current<size_read; current++){
                c=(*buf_1_ptr)[current];
                if(c>='0'){
                    temp*=10;
                    temp+=c-'0';
                }else if(c=='-'){
                    neg=-1;
                }else{
                    sum+=temp*neg;
                    temp=0;
                    neg=1;
                }
            }
            *can_proceed=true;
        }

    }
    wait(NULL);

    shmdt(shared_mem);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return sum+temp*neg;

}
```

Looking at the performance on my task manager, I assume what is stopping the execution are the both processes being stuck in the while loops.
While debugging using gdb, I noticed that the program skipped entirely the declaration of some pointers, especially the boolean ones.
Being this the first time working with shared memory between processes, I wouldn't be surprised if I wrote some unsafe code. If someone pointed out an error and/or a solution, it would be appreciated.

Comment: In general such a behaviour at runtime is due to an undefined behaviour in your code (caused by a ill-formed program). I would not be surprized if it would be due to some strict aliasing rule violation due to the `void*`/`void**` types. Can you add the right tag for the target language? C and C++ have different (sometimes incompatible) rules. I guess this is a C code.

Comment: So you would suggest to not create the swap function, but instead swap the pointers directly in the `somma()` function?

Comment: You can keep the function but use the right types. By the way, `while(!*can_proceed){}` is a good example of UB in C++ (which is AFAIK not UB in C). I do not see memory barrier in your code. I am not sure if this is required for shared memory but AFAIK it is (memory writes are not guaranteed to be sequentially consistent when read from another process).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I really don't know what UB means. English is not my native language.

Comment: Sorry, UB means Undefined Behaviour. (English is not my native language etiher ;) ). A program having an UB can be wrongly optimized by compilers since it is not supposed to happens. In fact, Compiler optimizers can even used these assumptions to optimize programs further.

Comment: TYSM. Do you think there is another way to communicate that the reading and processing have been terminated between the child and parent processes?

Comment: I would personally use signals to communicate between processes and possibly locks. AFAIK, there are versions working for processes. Shared memory is good to share data between processes but not for ensuring their synchronization. That being said, I am not sure your target platform will support this since it does not support threads (supported on all mainstream platform since decades).

Comment: I think that the eliminated threads support is voluntary from the maintainers of the website, to prevent submitters from abusing them. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Check if `fork()` returns an error (`-1`). Don't create a structure using dodgy pointer arithmetics. Compiler assumes other CPUs won't modify variables so `while(!*acknowledge_read){}` will be optimized to `for(;;) {}`, and you need to control cache coherency (marking shared variables as `volatile` won't fix all the problems). If you do fix all the problems (atomics/locks, etc); at best the waiting and synchronization will make it slower than the original single threaded code (at worst, the computer only has one CPU that spends most of its time "busy waiting" pointlessly).

Answer (score 0):

Many compiler optimizations are based upon the assumption that if a storage location identified via lvalue is caused or observed to hold a certain value, subsequent observations will yield that same value in the absence of any evidence that the storage might have been disturbed.  Beyond a few bare minimum requirements, the Standard waives jurisdiction, as a "quality of implementation" issue, over the the question of what forms of evidence an implementation would recognize as indicating the possibility of such disturbance.

If an lvalue has a `volatile` qualifier, that will generally be interpreted as requiring that a compiler treat the storage associated with that particular lvalue as subject to external change or observation without notice.  On most compilers which are designed to be suitable for low-level programming tasks and aren't based on clang or gcc, the fact that a volatile write to *anything* occurs between two other accesses to an object will be treated as evidence that the state of that object might be observed or modified in ways a compiler couldn't expect to understand. Both clang and gcc, however, treats the Standard's waiver of jurisdiction over quality-of-implementation issues as implying that all possible treatments are equally good, and thus both are willfully blind to such evidence of potential disturbance.  When using clang or gcc, if a storage location might be changed via means that clang or gcc don't understand, one must either:

1. Refer to the storage location *exclusively*, throughout the entire program, using the "atomic" types that were added in C11.
2. Access the storage location exclusively using `volatile`-qualified lvalues.
3. Precede and follow any attempts to read the storage using "ordinary" lvalues with "memory barrier" or "memory clobber" directives *and* ensure that nothing can change the value of the storage between those directives.  Even if it would be acceptable for a read to yield any of the values the storage holds between two memory-clobber or memory-barrier directives, gcc (and probably clang) may sometimes behave in a manner that's not consistent with any value the storage could *ever* hold.  Given e.g. `int temp1 = *p;`, gcc will sometimes eliminate the need for `temp1` by rewriting places that use `temp` to use `*p` instead.

Depending upon what a program needs to do, any of the above might be the most practical way of doing it, but one should bear all three possibilities in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some searching, and thanks to the suggestions provided by [@Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard),  I managed to eliminate the need of the while loops, which were optimized out as `while(true)` because of the initialization of the boolean variables to `true`. Apparently, modifying them in a shared memory space does not prevent GCC from optimizing them out.
I used signals and in particular the `kill()` and `sigwait()` functions to send and wait signals respectively.

EDIT: As pointed out from [@Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559737/brendan), the code using fork() is actually slower, also because the platform I'm submitting on sums up the time of all processes anyway. Thanks anyway to everyone for the help.

Anyway, here's the final code:

```c
#define _SVID_SOURCE

#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<signal.h>

#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast,no-stack-protector,unroll-loops,fast-math")
#pragma GCC target("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4.1,sse4.2,avx,avx2,popcnt,tune=native")

#define buf_size 0x10000

#define acknowledge_read SIGUSR1
#define can_swap SIGUSR2

long long somma(FILE *__restrict__ f){
    size_t size_read;
    long long sum=0;
    int current=0, neg=0, temp=0;

    int fd=fileno(f);
    char c;

    key_t shm_key=ftok("bigsomma_async.c", 65);
    if(shm_key==-1){
        perror("ftok");
    }

    //set up the various pointers for shared memory
    size_t *size_read_ptr;
    char* buf_1;
    char* buf_2;
    char** buf_1_ptr;
    char** buf_2_ptr;

    //allocate sequentially for size, two buffers, pointers to buffers
    int shmid=shmget(shm_key, 
                                sizeof(size_t)+
                                sizeof(char)*buf_size+
                                sizeof(char)*buf_size+
                                sizeof(char*)+
                                sizeof(char*)
                            , IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }

    char* shared_mem=(char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_mem == (char*)-1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return 1;
    }

    //set up the pointers to the respective location
    size_read_ptr=(size_t*)(shared_mem);
    buf_1=(char*)(size_read_ptr+1);
    buf_2=(char*)(buf_1+buf_size);
    buf_1_ptr=(char**)(buf_2+buf_size);
    buf_2_ptr=(char**)(buf_1_ptr+1);

    *size_read_ptr=1;
    *buf_1_ptr=buf_1;
    *buf_2_ptr=buf_2;

    //set the signals to capture (SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2)
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);  //clear the set of signals
    sigaddset(&set, can_swap);  //add the two signals
    sigaddset(&set, acknowledge_read);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL); //set so that the signals get intercepted and blocked

    int none;   //to capture the signals, do not need really in this case, only for correct usage of sigwait

    pid_t pfork=fork();
    if(!pfork){
        pid_t ppid=getppid();
        while(*size_read_ptr!=0){

            sigwait(&set, &none);   //wait for the size to be acknowledged from the parent
            *size_read_ptr=read(fd, buf_2, buf_size);

            sigwait(&set, &none);   //wait for the parent to parse the input

            char* tmp=*buf_1_ptr;       //swap the buffers
            *buf_1_ptr=*buf_2_ptr;
            *buf_2_ptr=tmp;

            kill(ppid, can_swap);       //tell the parent that he can start parsing
        }
        exit(0);
    }else{
        kill(pfork, acknowledge_read);  //send the initial signals so the child doesn't hang
        kill(pfork, can_swap);

        int size_read;
        while(*size_read_ptr!=0){
            sigwait(&set, &none);   //wait for the read and swap to complete

            size_read=*size_read_ptr;
            //tell the child that the size has been acquired, and another read can be performed while the input is processes
            kill(pfork, acknowledge_read);

            //parsing the numbers
            for(current=0; current<size_read; current++){
                c=(*buf_1_ptr)[current];
                if(c>='0'){
                    temp*=10;
                    temp+=c-'0';
                }else if(c=='-'){
                    neg=-1;
                }else{
                    sum+=temp*neg;
                    temp=0;
                    neg=1;
                }
            }

            //tell the child that the buffers can now be swapped
            kill(pfork, can_swap);
        }

    }
    wait(NULL);

    shmdt(shared_mem);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return sum+temp*neg;

}
```